# importing excel files in r

Tags: r, import, xlsx

i am trying to load an excel file in r studio but each time i run it

```
Error in read_excel("R/win-library/3.6/IMDB_data.xlsx", sheet = "IMDB_data",
  : 
  could not find function "read_excel" this is displayed.
 i have tried changing directory
saving the data to load, in the same as working directory
none of the articles resolve my issues concerned yet
tried changing directory
saving the file in the same place as my working directory
importing through choose directory


setwd("~/R/win-library/3.6")
library(readxl)
IMDB_data <- read_excel("R/win-library/3.6/IMDB_data.xlsx", 
                        sheet = "IMDB_data", skip = 2)
```

1. Write R code using data “IMDB_data” to
2. Load CSV in R by skipping second row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6SCm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `readxl` library is not loaded.
Do you get any errors when you run `library(readxl)`?
Your working folder shouldn't matter and you should probably avoid working in the R's library.
The `read_excel` command should read the file based on the path provided, but your error is not complaining about the missing file. It's complaining about the missing function.
Lastly, if you set the working directory to `~/R/win-library/3.6`, then it would be enough to run the following code (provided your `readxl` library loaded correctly):

```
IMDB_data <- read_excel("IMDB_data.xlsx", sheet = "IMDB_data", skip = 2)
```